# procedure to insert into tabl

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to insert values into status table using the following procedure. I'm getting compilation errors. Can anyone please explain the problem to me?

```
SQL> create or replace procedure statusupdate(ptid in train.tid%type,pdate in da
te)
 2  is
 3  pseats train.totalseats%type;
 4  begin
 5  select totalseats into pseats from train where tid=ptid;
 6  insert into status values(ptid,pdate,pseat);
 7  exception
 8  dbms_output.put_line('something wrong...ERROR!');
 9  end;
 10  /
```

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace procedure statusupdate(ptid in train.tid%type, pdate in date)
is
  pseats train.totalseats%type;
begin
  select totalseats into pseats from train where tid = ptid;
  insert into status values(ptid, pdate, pseats);
  exception when others then
    dbms_output.put_line('something wrong...ERROR!');
end;
```

Errors I found in your version:
Line 6: wrong name "pseat"
Line 7: wrong syntax of "exception catching" block. You have to tell Oracle which exceptions you want to handle in with a WHEN clause